# Hyperledger Fabric: How to trim logs?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

We have been running a fabric network for a while and the docker containers ran out of disk space because of the logs. How can we trim the logs so that they don't take up more than e.g., 1GB of disk space? Older messages should be discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it sounds like you are running Fabric in Docker, you should just use Docker's native logging options.  Sounds like you are just using the default logging which means the `json-file` driver.  You can either specify Docker-wide settings or per container settings.

Here's an example of a `daemon.json` file to set global options to limit log file size to 10m and limit the number of log files to keep to 3:

```
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "3",
    "labels": "production_status",
    "env": "os,customer"
  }
}
```

If you are using docker-compose to run your containers, you can set per container logging options in your yams config file.

If you are starting containers using `docker run ....`, you can use the `--log-opt` flag, e.g. `docker run --log-opt max-file=3 --log-opt max-size=10m ...`.